# Bukkit plugin doesn't work (Spigot API)

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

So, I'm trying to create an example plugin but it won't work, it says in the console that the plugin.yml is not found even though I believe I've exported and have done everything correctly.

The main class:

```
package com.Jacksonbanan.helloworld;


import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class wwylih extends JavaPlugin{

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String [] args){
            if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("coincidence")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "I think not!");
            }
            return true;


    }

}
```

plugin.yml:

```
name: coincidence
version: 1.0
main: com.Jacksonbanan.helloworld.wwylih
commands:
    coincidence:
        usage: /<command>
        description: Displays a message.
```

Comment: There is definitely something going wrong with packaging your plugin. Can you please share how you packaged your plugin? If you change your .jar file to a .zip file (by simply renaming it) and unzip it, the config.yml should be in the root folder.

Comment: There is no config.yml at all

Comment: How have you exported the project?

Comment: I right clicked the project and pressed export and then choose where I should save it then pressed finish

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your plugin? Does it not load? Does the command not work? Does an error get thrown when you try to run the command? If there's any errors, can you please post them here, so we could help you out some more?

Comment: If I do /pl my plugin won't show up, I can not use the command and in the console when I run the server it says that plugin.yml does not exist even though it does and I am quite sure that I did everything the way you should, thanks

Comment: Or actually, it says in the console "Jar does not contain plugin.yml"

Comment: @Jacksonbanan I rolled back your edit so that the question can still be seen. Even if it isn't a great question, it might help someone else in the future.

Comment: Also, I believe you have the incorrect Chat Color imported. Last time I checked it was something like "org.bukkit.ChatColor" but I may be wrong. Just double check it Jackson :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse, click and drag the plugin.yml onto the folder named "src". Then export again.

You have your plugin.yml in the wrong spot.

Comment: I've already fixed it, thanks though and yes, this is what I did, so for anyone else that needs help with this, then this guy knows what he's doing!

Comment: @Jacksonbanan Please mark this answer as accepted (click the tick below it) if it was correct.

Comment: @IanKemp unfortunately since it looks like this person was just looking for a quick fix, they have not been online since March. So I doubt it'll get accepted.

Answer (score -3):

Use cmd.equalseIgnireCase not what ever you put in with label.

Comment: Please clarify or expand your answer.